# deploying Grails app with CloudFoundry plugin

Tags: grails, deployment, groovy, permgen, cloud-foundry

I use the Grails CloudFoundry plugin to deploy my Grails app. Almost as soon as the app has been started, it runs out of PermGen memory. Is there any way I can increase the amount of PermGen memory available?

I've seen [this thread](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20049126-is-it-possible-to-increase-permgen-space) on the CloudFoundry forum, but it doesn't help much because I'm using the CloudFoundry Grails plugin to deploy rather than the vmc tool that's mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to v1.2.1 of the plugin and see this bug for the syntax of how to use the `cf-env-add` script: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCLOUDFOUNDRY-28

Comment: If I run that command once, will it use those settings every time I subsequently run `grails cf-push`, `grails cf-update`, etc?

Comment: Yes - the settings are kept at the server. Run `grails cf-env` to see the vars that you've set.